# Build Indoor map tracking with Here

Tags: here-api

I want build indoor tracking web application with angular 8.Can i use **Here** for the same.If yes,Do i need to use venue maps or normal map will be ok? Please share link for any indoor tracking example with Here.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly about Here approach, but [Navigine](https://navigine.com/developers/)  provides an Angular-based library for indoor tracking application (by request).